# Does Nancy.Testing support nested Razor views?

Tags: unit-testing, razor, nancy

I have a unit test that attempts to sign-in with incorrect credentials and checks the resulting response body for some specific 'errorbox' html. This works just fine.

```
[Fact]
public void SignIn__Should_display_error_message_when_error_passed()
{
    var browser = Fake.Browser();
    var response = browser.Get("/signin", with => with.Query("error", "true"));

    response.Body["#errorBox"]
            .ShouldExistOnce()
            .And.ShouldBeOfClass("floatingError")
            .And.ShouldContain("invalid", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

My pages were getting a bit repetitious so I re-organised things to create a simple set of nested razor views, like this:

**The SignIn View**

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<dynamic>
@{
    Layout = "_Master.cshtml";
}
<h3>Sign In</h3>
<form class="nice" method="POST">
    ... [labels, inputs etc]
</form> 
@if (Model.HasError)
{
  <div id="errorBox" class="floatingError">Invalid UserName or Password</div>
}
```

**The _Master View**

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<dynamic>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@Model.Title</title>  
        ... [css javascript etc]
        @RenderSection("Head", required: false)      
    </head>

    <body>
        @RenderBody()        
    </body>
</html>
```

This still works and my unit test still passes (bear with me). Time passes and the code gets more complex, so now I need to reorganise again. I have added another layer of nesting to my razor views.

**The _Page View**

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<dynamic>
@{
    Layout = "_Master.cshtml";
}
@section Head{
    [... shared javascript, css]
    @RenderSection("Head", required: false)  
}
[.. some shared content]
@RenderBody()
```

The double nesting looks like this:

**SignIn -> _Page -> _Master**

Now my unit test *fails* as the response does not contain the correct html. Running the code in an real browser (chrome) and manually supplying incorrect credentials produces the correct response, it is only the unit-test that fails.

Drilling down to `response.Body.responseDocument.agilityPackDocumentInternal.DocumentNode.InnerHtml` shows this exception:

*Error Compiling Template: (15, 11) The type or namespace name 'XXXX' could not be found*

Re-pointing the SignIn view back to using _Master as its layout (cutting out the middle _Page view) makes the Unit Test pass again.

Yet the _Page view does nothing code-wise, it just adds some `<script>` and `<style>` tags and passes on the baton. To test if those tags are the problem, I shifted them to the _Master view and kept the nesting at one level (SignIn -> _Master) and the test passed.

So, does `Nancy.Testing` support two levels of razor layout nesting? Otherwise, can anybody spot my mistake?

Thank You

**P.S.** I don't know if it is connected but I suspected that view caching might be the problem (after reading [Test driving Nancy Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365306/test-driving-nancy-modules)) I checked the value of `Nancy.StaticConfiguration.DisableCaches` and sure enough, it was set to `false` (despite my `DEBUG` symbol being switched on and running the test in Debug mode). I set this value to true in my custom unit test BootStrapper class but this made no difference.

```
protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
{
    base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
    Nancy.StaticConfiguration.DisableCaches = true;
}
```

Comment: I have opened a a new question with more refined information. Please check it out: [Why does Nancy.Testing fail when @using statements are included in razor layouts?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12052267/776476)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found in my follow up question:

[Why does Nancy.Testing fail when @using statements are included in razor layouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12052267/776476)